# async foreach and mongoose in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, foreach

in mongoose I make relationship like mongoose document now I want get an array of object

objects are children of object we have

for example in tweeter one user has so many tweets and each tweet has title, content and author

and someone give us user id and we give him array of title and content of all tweet user have

```
[
{title: 'title01', content: 'aaaaaa'},
{title: 'title02', content: 'bbbbb'},
.
.
.
]
```

I try

```
    const username = req.params.username;
    User.find({ username: username }, (err, docs) => {
      if (err) return res.json({ err: true });
      if (docs.length > 0) {
        let lives: Array<Object> = [];
        docs[0].lives.forEach((live, idx) => {
          Live.find({ _id: live }, (err, docs) => {
            lives.push(docs[0]);
          });
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({ err: true });
      }
    });
```

lives has title content and author(in DB I named it user)
but because aSync i cant get lives after forEach
:)

UPDATED:

schema for live:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
    required: true,
  },
});
```

schema for user:

```
import { ArraySortOptions } from "joi";
import mongoose, { Model } from "mongoose";

interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  email: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  lives: Array<mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId>;
}

const schema: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lives: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "lives",
    },
  ],
});
const User: Model<IUser> = mongoose.model("users", schema);
export default User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use Mongoose's in-built [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.populate) method which lets you reference documents in other collections, similar to the join-like [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation operator found in MongoDB versions >= 3.2.

Since [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.populate) needs a query to attach itself to, use `User.findOne()` to query a single user who matches the username we provide in the argument.

Using async/await this can be done as follows:

```
const { username } = req.params;
const user = await User.findOne({ username }).populate('lives');
console.log(user.lives); // ---> [{title: 'title01', content: 'aaaaaa'}, { ... }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
const username = req.params.username;
User.find({ username: username }, async (err, docs) => {
  if (err) return res.json({ err: true });
  if (docs.length > 0) {
    // start with asnyc queries
    let livePromises = [];
    for (let live of docs[0].lives) {
      // push new promise which resolves the docs[0] of this live id
      livePromises.push(new Promise(resolve => {
        Live.find({ _id: live }, (err, docs) => {
          resolve(docs[0]);
        });
      }
    }
    // await all query results parallel
    let lives = await Promise.all(livePromises);
    // use lives variable as you want
    return res.json({ lives: lives });
  } else {
    return res.json({ err: true });
  }
});
```

I'm not sure, what kind of typed system you use (you wrote `lives: Array<Object>`), so I skipped it. Adapted my proposal as you like.
If you have any questions about this answer or on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in general, write a comment.

Comment: I use typescript

Comment: what Promise.all do ?

Comment: The [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method takes an iterable of promises as an input, and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises.